# No stream features to proceed using node-xmpp-client

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, xmpp, node-xmpp

I've installed prosody on an ubuntu AWS server. I have tried using Adium client and swift, but I get the same error indicated in the title. I've tried using node-xmpp-client to create a client but same error.

Node-XMPP client code:

```
const Client = require('node-xmpp-client');
const options = {
        jid: 'test@ec2-18-222-249-134.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com',
        password: 'password',
        host: 'ec2-18-222-249-134.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com'
}

       const client = new Client(options);
       client.once('online', connectionDetails =>{
       console.log('We are connected');
       console.log(connectionDetails);
});
```

Error Message:

```
Error: No stream features to proceed with
at Connection.onStanza (/Users/my-name/BeginXMPP/node_modules/node-xmpp-core/lib/Connection.js:363:17)
at StreamParser.<anonymous> (/Users/my-name/BeginXMPP/node_modules/node-xmpp- 
core/lib/Connection.js:231:10)
at StreamParser.emit (events.js:198:13)
at SaxLtx.<anonymous> (/Users/my-name/BeginXMPP/node_modules/@xmpp/streamparser/index.js:69:14)
at SaxLtx.emit (events.js:198:13)
at SaxLtx._handleTagOpening (/Users/my-name/BeginXMPP/node_modules/ltx/lib/parsers/ltx.js:40:12)
at SaxLtx.write (/Users/my-name/BeginXMPP/node_modules/ltx/lib/parsers/ltx.js:159:18)
at StreamParser.write (/Users/my-name/BeginXMPP/node_modules/@xmpp/streamparser/index.js:134:17)
at Connection.onData (/Users/my-name/BeginXMPP/node_modules/node-xmpp-core/lib/Connection.js:310:17)
at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15)
Emitted 'error' event at:
at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/my-name/BeginXMPP/node_modules/node-xmpp-client/lib/Client.js:158:23)
at Connection.emit (events.js:203:15)
```

Comment: if several different clients fail to connect, then the problem is not likely in yet another client - you've probably misconfigured prosody

Comment: @Bravo I figured it out. My letsencrypt cert was not configured

Comment: @DonCheeto Can you tell how did you solved it? I'm struggling here with the same error :) Also I'm using letsencrypt cert too.